# Unable to launch helm command in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Environment: AWS EC2

Verified I can run helm under generic ec2-user account, unable to get run it under individual users.

My user account returns this error:

```
WARNING: stat /home/$USER.config/helm/registry/config.json: permission denied 
/home/$USER/.config/helm/registry/config.json oras.land/oras-go/pkg/auth/docker.NewClientWithDockerFallback oras.land/oras-go@v1.2.3/pkg/auth/docker/client.go:80 helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/registry.NewClient helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/registry/client.go:83 main.newDefaultRegistryClient helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/root.go:277 main.newRootCmd helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/root.go:155 main.main helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:66 runtime.main runtime/proc.go:250 runtime.goexit runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598
```

I verified my $PATH has /usr/local/bin
Verified the permissions on helm, they're the same as kubectl which works fine

Comment: Using the ls -al command on the /home/$USER/ directory I found some incorrect user and group owners. Possibly from dir being copied over from other user.

used chmod -R $USER:$USER  ./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permission and fix is necessary the file permissions with the command:

```
ls -al /home/$USER.config/helm/registry/config.json
```

try this fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/747783/25579

Comment: No luck, it's throwing a permission denied then a does not a exist....

[kohen@vm01 ~]$ ls -al /home/$USER/.config/helm/registry/config.json
ls: cannot access /home/kohen/.config/helm/registry/config.json: Permission denied
[kohen@vm01 ~]$ sudo ls -al /home/$USER/.config/helm/registry/config.json
ls: cannot access /home/kohen/.config/helm/registry/config.json: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to fix the files permission with chmod or chown